# commandButton Rerender attribute issue

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this outputText block within the **dateSelection** pageBlock of my page.

```
<apex:outputText styleClass="dates" value="{0,date,MMM'.'dd', 'yyyy}">
     <apex:param value="{!propertyRate.Date__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

Here I have a **save** button. When I hit save, the dateSelection pageBlock rerenders. For some reason, the outputText above is the only part of the pageBlock that does NOT rerender. See image below.

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="dateSelection" status="updateDay"></apex:commandButton>
    <apex:actionStatus id="updateDay" startText="updating..." stopText=""/> 
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Before Hitting Save
[image: Before Hitting Save]

After Hitting Save (The bolded dates disapear in the left panel)
[image]

VF Page

```
    <apex:form >

        <apex:actionFunction name="dateSelected" action="{!setDate}" status="updatestatus" rerender="div">
            <apex:param name="dateId" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:actionStatus id="updatestatus" startText="updating..." stopText=""/>        

       <div id="leftBlock">
            <apex:pageBlock id="dateSelection" title="Date Selection">
                <div id="properyRates">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!property_rate_list}" var="propertyRate" id="propertyRateList">
                        <div class="propertyRateDiv">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="{!propertyRate.Id}" class="dateCheckbox" onchange="return verifyChecked($(this), '{!propertyRate.Id}');" />
                            <table class="propertyRateTable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <apex:outputText id="outputDates" styleClass="dates" value="{0,date,MMM'.'dd', 'yyyy}">
                                            <apex:param value="{!propertyRate.Date__c}" /> 
                                        </apex:outputText>
                                        <input type="hidden" class="property_rate_name" value="{!propertyRate.Name} {!propertyRate.id}"/>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>               
                                <tbody class="subText">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Housekeepers: </td>
                                        <td class="housekeepers">{!propertyRate.Housekeepers__c}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Properties: </td>
                                        <td class="properties">{!propertyRate.Properties__c}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>
        <div id="rightBlock">
            <apex:pageBlock title="Day Overview">
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!selectedDate.Housekeepers__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="dateSelection, outputDates" status="updateDay"></apex:commandButton>
                    <apex:actionStatus id="updateDay" startText="updating..." stopText=""/> 
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            </apex:pageBlock>

        </div>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using two `<apex:pageBlock>` components but only rerendering one of them (**dateSelection**).

Give the `<apex:outputText>` component an ID and then add that ID to the reRender attribute of the `<apex:commandButton>`

**edit**

So with your updated outputText:

```
    <apex:outputText id="outputDates" styleClass="dates" value="{0,date,MMM'.'dd', 'yyyy}">
         <apex:param value="{!propertyRate.Date__c}" /> 
 </apex:outputText>
```

Update your button to reRender it:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="dateSelection, outputDates" status="updateDay"></apex:commandButton>
```

Also I don't know your full page code so apologies if it's there, but you should add a messages component to display any errors that occur:

```
<apex:pageMessages id="messageBlock" />
```

Then update your buttons to reRender this too:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="dateSelection, outputDates, messageBlock" status="updateDay"></apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: Is this how it should be written? (With a comma separating them) rerender="dateSelection, outputDates" If so, that didn't work

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes comma separate the IDs, that should work. Could you post your full page code?

Comment: Yep! I've just posted the VF portion of the page. Let me know if you need CSS or JS, but they aren't that relevant to this.

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: Thanks, I've added in the messageBlock... For some reason the solution of adding an id to the outputText and then rerendering the ID at the commandButton, is not working

Comment: That's strange. Print the contents of propertyRate.Date__c out in your save() method and make sure it's being set correctly.

Comment: Ok, I just moved the outputText into a <td> tag. Originally it was in a <tr> tag. Now it is working. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working!